# Excel VBA Copying 18:00 as 0,750000000003

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks, one of them is password protected.

```
Sub WorkTime()
Dim Employee1 As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Employee1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="J:\Firm\Time\Employee1.xlsx", Password:="emp")
    MsgBox (Employee1.Sheets(1).Range("$E3:$E3").Value)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The value in the Employee-Workbook is 18:00 but when I display it in the MsgBox it comes out as 0,75000000000000003. Every other cell which has a formular in it I already tested aswell and they all display their correct value

Comment: @Gustav Oh my... Thanks! It worked. If you could write it as an answer I can accept your answer then ^^

Comment: The floating-point error is interesting, since 0.75 should be accurately representable in binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the *numeric* time value for 18:00.

Apply a time format or use `CDate` to convert to a true *DateTime* value. –